# Android Retrofit 2 + RxJava: listen to endless stream

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

Can I use Retrofit + RxJava to listen to an endless stream? For instance the Twitter stream. What I have is this:

```
public interface MeetupAPI {
    @GET("http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps/")
    Observable<RSVP> getRSVPs();
}

MeetupAPI api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MeetupAPI.RSVP_API)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MeetupAPI.class);

api.getRSVPs()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(rsvp -> Log.d(TAG, "got rsvp"),
                error -> Log.d(TAG, "error: " + error),
                () -> Log.d(TAG, "onComplete"));
```

but the "onComplete" is invoked after the first object has been parsed. Is there a way to tell Retrofit to stay open until further notice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Here my solution:**

You can use the @Streaming annotation:

```
public interface ITwitterAPI {

    @GET("/2/rsvps")
    @Streaming
    Observable<ResponseBody> twitterStream();
}

ITwitterAPI api = new Retrofit.Builder()
          .baseUrl("http://stream.meetup.com")
          .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
          .build().create(ITwitterAPI.class);
```

With `@Streaming` we can get raw input From `ResponseBody`.

Here my function to wrap body divided by lines with events:

```
public static Observable<String> events(BufferedSource source) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            try {
                while (!source.exhausted()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(source.readUtf8Line());
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And result usage:

```
api.twitterStream()
  .flatMap(responseBody -> events(responseBody.source()))
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

**upd about gracefully stopping**

When we unsubscribing, retrofit closes inputstream. But impossible to detect inputstream closed or not from inputstream themselves, so only way - try reading from stream - we gets exception with `Socket closed` message. 
We can interpret this exception as closing:

```
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            boolean isCompleted = false;
            try {
                while (!source.exhausted()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(source.readUtf8Line());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (e.getMessage().equals("Socket closed")) {
                    isCompleted = true;
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } else {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
            //if response end we get here
            if (!isCompleted) {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
```

And if connection closed because response end, we haven't any exceptions. Here `isCompleted` check for that. Let me know if i am wrong :)

Comment: I used your code but it doesn't work. The network call is performed only one once but I doesn't obtain any response or any error. @zella

Comment: link to my code https://gist.github.com/davideagostini/33223f4697e82bff9f4747580e608391

Answer (score 1):

[Zella's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996639/zella) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643377/7011748) is right for Retrofit2 with rxJava,
For rxJava2, I modified custom observable like this:

```
//imports
import io.reactivex.Observable                              
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable                  
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers                   
import okio.BufferedSource                   
import java.io.IOException                             



fun events(source: BufferedSource): Observable<String> {         
    return Observable.create { emitter ->                        
        var isCompleted = false                                  
        try {                                                    
            while (!source.exhausted()) {                        
                emitter.onNext(source.readUtf8Line()!!)          
            }                                                    
            emitter.onComplete()                                 
        } catch (e: IOException) {                               
            e.printStackTrace()                                  
            if (e.message == "Socket closed") {                  
                isCompleted = true                               
                emitter.onComplete()                             
            } else {                                             
                throw IOException(e)                             
            }                                                    
        }                                    
        if (!isCompleted) {                                      
            emitter.onComplete()                                 
        }                                                        
    }                                                            
}
```

Changes in module level build.gradle dependencies:

```
//retrofit rxJava2 adapter
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.1'

//rx-java
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

Retrofit Adapter Changes:

```
ITwitterAPI api = new Retrofit.Builder()
          .baseUrl("http://stream.meetup.com")
          .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
          .build().create(ITwitterAPI.class);
```

And Called the Streaming API as

```
api.twitterStream()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap { responseBody-> events(responseBody.source()) }
        .subscribe({ t ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onNext t=$t")
        }, { e ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onError e=$e")
        }, {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFinish")
        })
```

Comment: I used your code but it doesn't work. The network call is performed only one once but I doesn't obtain any response or any error.

Comment: link to my code https://gist.github.com/davideagostini/33223f4697e82bff9f4747580e608391